# Drawing Curves of Mahalanobis Distance while Specifying a Feature Vector in Bayes Decision Theory in R

Tags: r, classification, bayesian, pattern-recognition, mahalanobis

I'm studying pattern recognition and statistics.I like to use direct functions in R rather than explicitly writing codes.
 My question is that
in a three class 2-dimensional problem, my feature vectors for each class are normally distributed with covariance matrix

`s <- matrix(c(1.2,0.4,0.4,8),nrow=2)`
and mean vectors for each class are

`m1 <- t(c(0.1, 0.1));m2 <- t(c(2.1, 1.9));m3 <- t(c(-1.5, 2.0))`

Assuming that classes are equally probable, 
    I want to classify the feature vector

`x <- t(c(1.6,1.5))`

according to the Bayes Minimum Error Probability Classifier which i did successfully and **Now i want to draw the curves of Mahalanobis distance**.

I tried with `mahalanobis(x, center, cov, inverted = FALSE, ...)` function within `{stats}` package. But i get confuse because i have already mean and var-cov matrix  in my problem and `mahalanobis()` function doesn't provide facility for my problem!or it does? i don't know!

Kindly anyone please guide me how to calculate Mahalanobis distance with reference to my problem in particular and to draw curves of Mahalanobis distance. Thanks in Advance!

A specimen of above problem is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for with curves, but with regard to using the mahalanobis function, simply put the mean and covariance matrix in as arguments.

```
dat <- iris[,-5]
mahal <- mahalanobis(x = dat, center = colMeans(dat), cov = cov(dat))
```

Comment: can you please revisit the question. I have added an image of the specimen question